# Brunch.io and Compass , bad font-face generadted by libsass

Tags: compass, brunch, libsass

Well, I'm using [Brunch.io](http://brunch.io/) to replace the traditionnal Grunt.js. To perfom the build very fast, I've set on my brunch-config.coffee file, the "native" mode, and I've downloaded all the [compass mixins](https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins/tree/master/lib)

```
  plugins:
    sass:
      mode: 'native'
```

I've not tryed all the compass-mixins, but everything seem's allright, except when I try to include web-font, so adding this on a  _font.scss file for exemple :

```
@include font-face("oxy_reg",
        font-files("oxygen-regular-webfont.eot",
                   "oxygen-regular-webfont.svg",
                   "oxygen-regular-webfont.ttf",
                   "oxygen-regular-webfont.woff"
        ));
```

result this on the generated css file :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "oxy_reg";
  src: font-files("oxygen-regular-webfont.eot", "oxygen-regular-webfont.svg", "oxygen-regular-webfont.ttf", "oxygen-regular-webfont.woff"); }
```

but it's not a good css format, the right one  (doing by ruby, when I set mode to "ruby" on the brunch-config.coffee) should be this :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "oxy_reg";
    src: url('oxygen-regular-webfont.eot?1422206651') format('embedded-opentype'), url('oxygen-regular-webfont.svg?1422206651') format('svg'), url('oxygen-regular-webfont.ttf?1422206651') format('truetype'), url('oxygen-regular-webfont.woff?1422206651') format('woff'); }
```

well, I've got no error, but the generated script is not good !

Hope someone get a idea what I'm doing wrong !

see you

Comment: It appears to be a bug in compass-mixins, which you should report on that project's issue tracker.

Comment: Thank's for your reply  es128, effectively, i've found this to, well, unfortunately, i'm back with Grunt cause Brunch.io is great but not reach all my expects for the moment.